# Python Recursively Maintain Keyed Depth

Tags: python, recursion

## Input/Goal

My input data is an OrderedDict for which there can be a variable depth of nested OrderedDicts so I have opted to handle parsing this output recursively. The desired output is a csv with header.

## Elaboration of Problem

My code below will work once I am able to correctly define `field_name` upon traversing back up a branch after completing all of a branch's leaves. (i.e. `Type_1.Field_3.Data` will incorrectly be called `Type_1.Field_2.Field_3.Data`).

Once the leaves on a branch have been exhausted, I want to remove the last `.Field_x` from the `field_name` so that a new (correct) one can be added for the following object.

## Request for Help

Does anyone see where I can include this feature? Thanks,

...

## Dependencies:

---

#### Code Snippet:

```
def get_soql_fields(soql):
    soql_fields = re.search('(?<=select)(?s)(.*)(?=from)', soql)  # get fields
    soql_fields = re.sub(' ', '', soql_fields.group())  # remove extra spaces
    fields = re.split(',|\n|\r', soql_fields)  # split on commas and newlines
    fields = [field for field in fields if field != '']  # remove empty strings
    return fields

def parse_output(data, soql):
    fields = get_soql_fields(soql)
    header = fields

    master = [header]

    for record in data['records']:  # for each 'record' in response
        row = []

        for obj, value in record.iteritems():  # for each obj in record
            if isinstance(value, basestring):  # if query base object has desired fields
                if obj in fields:
                    row.append(value)

            elif isinstance(value, dict):  # traverse down into object
                path = obj
                row.append(_traverse_output(obj, value, fields, row, path))
        master.append(row)
    return master

def _traverse_output(obj, value, fields, row, path):
    for f, v in value.iteritems():  # for each item in obj
        if not isinstance(v, (dict, list, tuple)):
            field_name = '{path}.{name}'.format(path=path, name=f)  # TODO fix this to full field name

            print('FName: {0}'.format(field_name))

            if field_name in fields:
                print('match')
                row.append(v)

        elif isinstance(v, dict):  # it is a dict
            path += '.{obj}'.format(obj=f)
            _traverse_output(f, v, fields, row, path)
```

#### Example Salesforce SOQL:

```
select
    Type_1.Field_1,
    Type_1.Field_2.Data,
    Type_1.Field_3,
    Type_1.Field_4,
    Type_1.Field_5.Data_1.Data,
    Type_1.Field_6,
    Type_2.Field_1,
    Type_2.Field_2
from
    Obj_1
limit
    1
;
```

#### Example Salesforce Output:

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Obj_1",
            "url": "<url>"
        },
        "Type_1": {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Type_1",
                "url": "<url>"
            },
            "Field_1": "<stuff>",
            "Field_2": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Field_2",
                    "url": "<url>"
                },
                "Data": "<data>"
            },
            "Field_3": "<data>",
            "Field_4": "<data>",
            "Field_5": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Field_2",
                    "url": "<url>"
                },
                "Data_1": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "Data_1",
                        "url": "<url>"
                    },
                    "Data": "<data>"
                }
            },
            "Field_6": 1.0
        },
        "Type_2": {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Type_2",
                "url": "<url>"
            },
            "Field_1": "<data>",
            "Field_2": "<data>"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but you can simplify to `not isinstance(v, (list,dict, tuple))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Noted and updated! Thanks for that catch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a quick solution for this. I'll just note what I figured out, and append the code I wrote to the end.

Essentially your problem is that you keep trying to modify `path` in place, which isn't going to work. Instead do something like

```
new_path = path + '.{obj}'.format(obj=f)
_traverse_output(f, v, fields, row, new_path)
```

A note about this: it will NOT necessarily result in a row where the values are in the same order as the header (i.e., if Type_1.Field_1 is in position 0 of the header list, then the value corresponding to it might not be).

The easy way to solve this (and handle csvs in general) is to use DictWriter from the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), then pass an empty dictionary to your first call where the keys will be the field names and the values will be their values.

Another way to solve the problem is to pre-populate your row list with None or empty strings, then use the `list.index` method to assign the value to the appropriate position.

I wrote an implementation of `_traverse_output` as examples for each, though they differ slightly from your code. They take an element of the `'records'` list.

**Dictionary Example**

```
def _traverse_output_with_dict(record, fields, row_values, field_name=''):
    for obj, value in record.iteritems():
        new_field_name = '{}.{}'.format(field_name, obj) if field_name else obj
        print new_field_name
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            if new_field_name in fields:
                row_values[new_field_name] = value
        else:
            _traverse_output_with_dict(value, fields, row_values, new_field_name)
```

**List Example**

```
def _traverse_output_with_list(record, fields, row, field_name=''):
    while len(row) < len(fields):
        row.append('')

    for obj, value in record.iteritems():
        new_field_name = '{}.{}'.format(field_name, obj) if field_name else obj
        print new_field_name
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            if new_field_name in fields:
                row[fields.index(new_field_name)] = value
        else:
            _traverse_output_with_list(value, fields, row, new_field_name)
```

Comment: I cannot find the difference between how you handle 'field_name' and my code. I do not understand how `if field_name else obj` affects this.

Comment: Regarding the order of output, as I am working with an ordered dictionary input, parsing it, and outputing a list of lists, I do not have to worry about additionally ensuring correct order via list index or dictionary.

Comment: By using your answer and adapting parts of it to my code, I have a working solution. Thank you!